# Chromecast Chrome Extension Injects API as Japanese Characters

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I can't seem to find this problem anywhere else and I'm getting frustrated with it. Basically, I have whitelisted my device successfully and I am starting to develop a simple 'Hello World' application using Chrome as my sender. I went in and I whitelisted `localhost` in the Chromecast extension and added `data-cast-api-enabled="true"` to the html tag of my sender page. It even seems as if the extension is trying to inject the API.

But, in the Chrome debugger I get an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

I looked in the network tab and saw that `api_script.js` was coming in from the extension and I could even open it in a separate tab. But, for some reason this page is interpreting this javascript file as...well, what appears to be Japanese. In the network tab, the response for the request for `api_script.js` is (and this is just abbreviated):

....慶⁲慣瑳㴠挠獡⁴籼笠㭽挊獡⹴䅎䕍㴠∠慃瑳灁≩਻慣瑳嘮剅䥓乏㴠嬠ⰲ㐠㭝挊獡⹴敒散癩牥㴠映湵瑣潩⡮摩‬慮敭 ੻
桴獩椮⁤‽摩਻†桴獩渮浡⁥‽慮敭਻†桴獩椮味扡牐橯捥整⁤‽桴獩椮䅰摤敲獳㴠渠汵੬㭽挊獡⹴慌湵档敄捳楲瑰潩⁮‽畦据
湯⤨笠 琠楨⹳牵⁬‽桴獩琮硥⁴‽畮汬紊਻慣瑳䰮畡据剨煥敵瑳㴠映湵瑣潩⡮捡楴楶祴祔数‬敲散癩牥 ੻†桴獩愮瑣癩瑩呹灹
‽捡楴楶祴祔数਻†桴獩爮捥楥敶⁲‽敲散癩牥਻†桴獩搮獥牣灩楴湯㴠琠楨⹳慰慲敭整獲㴠渠汵㭬 琠楨⹳楤捳湯敮瑣潐楬
㴠∠潣瑮湩敵ਢ...

I'm not really sure why this is happening. It seems like copying the API code directly into my webpage is the only way I can get this thing working at all. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chromecast is interpreting your script as UTF-16 (as proof, I pasted that garbage and saved it as UTF-16-LE, and got a text file starting with `var cast = cast || {};`).

Make sure you don't have a BOM header on the script. If the problem is due to charset detection, try adding some extended-ASCII characters in a comment near the beginning to force charset detection to pick e.g. UTF-8.

Comment: Derp...that did it. Looks like the file was getting saved in UTF-16 for some reason. Thanks!